# Is "on account of I wasn't coming back" correct usage?

Tags: phrase-usage

I sometimes encounter the phrase 'on account of' in conjunction with a simple declarative phrase, as in the example from J.D. Salinger's *Catcher in the Rye*: "He'd written me this note asking me to stop by and say good-by before vacation started, **on account of I wasn't coming back**."

Is this grammatical or technically incorrect? Could it be a regional or temporal idiosyncrasy?

Answer (score 2):

"On account of" is a rather long-winded way of saying "because", normally followed by a noun, as in "We were late, on account of a train-strike."  So strictly, I guess that clause ought to be "on account of *the fact that* I wasn't coming back", which would be even more long-winded.  But in informal speech, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_account_of) actually covers this usage:

> **on account of**
>
> (idiomatic) Because of, due to, owing to.    (idiomatic) For the sake
>   of.
>
> (regional, idiomatic) Because.
>
> (US, colloquial) On account of the fact that: because, since.

I'd say that the tags 'regional' / 'US, colloquial' identify the because/since usage as non-standard in the UK, and as not used generally in formal registers in the US.